# Does Rikimaru's backstab and critical damage from items stack?

Tags: dota-2

Does [Rikimaru](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Riki)'s passive **Backstab** stack with ***critical damage***?

Is there a chance that my damage will be equal to this

*Normal attack* + *backstab* + *critical damage*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

Here is the description to the Backstab skill from Rikimaru

> If Riki attacks from behind, bonus damage is applied based on his current agility.

That said, all attacks from behind will do extra damage that can be calculated (ignoring armor resistance) by adding the ammount added to the base damage from your character.

Here is some information about [how Critical Strikes work](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Critical_strike):

> Critical damage is physical damage and reduced by various types of armor. The red number shown by critical strike is displayed before reductions (this is why illusions don't show very low red numbers). Critical strike does not work against buildings and is subject to pseudo-random distribution. Because critical strike multiplies the attack damage of a unit, it is a scaling ability (unlike the damage of Monkey King Bar's mini-bash ability).

Backstab and critical strike can proc in the same attack. Period.
What's not clear here is **when** will the critical strike bonus be calculated.

The backstab skill adds bonus damage to your atacks based on your agility, and critical strikes have a chance of **x** to multiply by **y** your atack damage.

Lets say critical strike damage is the last parameter to be calculated. That would lead us to something like this ( I picked the values )

> Attack Base : 50 , Backstab Bonus : 40 , Critical Strike Multipler : 2
>
> Total Damage = (50 + 40) * 2 = 180

On the other hand, if Backstab bonus is added after the Critical Strike sums up, we would end up having :

> Attack Base : 50 , Backstab Bonus : 40 , Critical Strike Multipler : 2
>
> Total Damage = (50*2) + 40 = 140

**TL:DR**

Whether the Critical Strike is calculated after or before Backstab sums up, is not clear, but they CAN proc in the same attack.

Comment: Can this not be easily tested?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience from Dota 1, the backstab does not proc at the same time as the crit damage.

This is how it roughly goes :

1- You hit the ennemy from the back
2- The backstab skill procs, deals the added bonus damage from behind
3- The critical chance gets calculated
4- The normal damage procs

Comment: Worth noting is that many of these subtle interactions have been changed from original DotA to Dota2. This might be one of those cases (and is pretty easy to test).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, the bonus damage from backstab is NOT included in the base for crit.

So if you crit it will be your base dmg x crit bonus + backstab dmg.

The same can be said for cleave dmg, only the base dmg contributes towards the cleave.

However you can lifesteal the dmg dealt via backstab.